# How to format paragraph spacing in HTMLBody?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written an Outlook email using an Excel macro. The paragraph spacing of the lines is set to "Auto". I would like the spacing to be "0 pt" both before and after.

Is there a way to dictate the appropriate paragraph format?

```
Sub Email_Budget()

   Dim objOutlook As Object
   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   Dim objEmail As Object
   Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

   Dim CaseCount As Long
   CaseCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B6:B500"))
   'Debug.Print CaseCount

   Dim i As Integer

   With objEmail
      .To = "abc@xyz.com"
      .Subject = "TEST1: May 2019 Budget"
      .HTMLBody = "Karen,<br><br>"
      .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "The potential " & _
        MonthName(Month(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"))) & _
        " invoices are below.<br><br>"

      For i = 1 To CaseCount

          If ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 4).Value = "Yes" Then
              .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<ul style='list-style-type:disc;'>" & _
                "<li>" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 2).Value & " - " & _
                Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 6).Value, "Currency") & _
                " (" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 8).Value, "Currency") & _
                " without budget or invoicing)." & "</li>" & "</ul>"
          End If

      Next i

      .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>Thank you,<br>Kurt"
      .Display
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your mail is in HTML format, so you need to use css if you want to adjust the formatting. BTW you are writing `<ul>` and `</ul>` for every list item - you should just write `<ul>` before you enter the loop, and then `</ul>` when the loop is done.  Fixing that may resolve your spacing problem.

Comment: I guess I'm still slightly off - my macro won't run if I type: <ul> before and </ul> after the for loop.  I get a message saying "Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement."  I'm assuming it wants me to close the </ul> on the same line..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to format emails like this is to write the email in Outlook with formatting, send it to yourself, then right-click the body of the email and select View Source. You can then pick out the relevant sections of HTML.

In your case, I believe you want to add these two style options to set the before/after spacing:

`style='mso-margin-top-alt:0.0pt;margin-bottom:0.0pt;'`

Comment: Per your recommendation I tried to add:  "<ul style='list-style-type:disc;mso-margin-top-alt:0.0pt;margin-bottom-alt:0.0pt;'>"  but the bullet points of the email still appear spaced out...  When I open the View Source of an email whose format I want to use, i think what I am looking for is below. My question is how to implement p.MsoNormal or li.MsoNormal into my macro?

Comment: p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
 {margin:0in;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}

Comment: I think I resolved the issue. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `<ul>` and `</ul>` for every list item - you should just write `<ul>` before you enter the loop, and then `</ul>` when the loop is done. Fixing that may resolve your spacing problem

```
   With objEmail
      .To = "abc@xyz.com"
      .Subject = "TEST1: May 2019 Budget"
      .HTMLBody = "Karen,<br><br>"
      .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "The potential " & _
                  MonthName(Month(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"))) & _
                  " invoices are below.<br><br><ul style='list-style-type:disc;'>"

      For i = 1 To CaseCount
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 4).Value = "Yes" Then

            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<li>" & ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 2).Value & _
                        " - " & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 6).Value, "Currency") & _
                        " (" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 8).Value, "Currency") & _
                        " without budget or invoicing)." & "</li>"


        End If
      Next i
      .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</ul><br>Thank you,<br>Kurt"
      .Display
   End With
```